# Navbar links are working wrong in Jekyll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, liquid

I added a simple navbar with 3 nav tabs using twitter bootstrap on Github pages, but I don't know why it is behaving strange.

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Code<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="category/life/index.html">Life</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="aboutme.html">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

1. On the page of Life, when clicking on About, somehow it requests below url and it gives a 404. Of course 404 but why wouldn't it go straight to aboutme.html in the base url? About page works fine when is clicked on the homepage.

https://yinkouya.github.io/category/life/aboutme.html

2. On the page of Life, when clicking on Life again, it's 404 like this:

https://yinkouya.github.io/category/life/category/life/index.html

Clearly something is wrong, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: your root directory is https://yinkouya.github.io/category/life/  . So please change it accordingly. With the code you have presented above i can infer only this. Thank you

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: It is redirecting you to the `href` from the root directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with Bootstrap but with how Jekyll are generating the URLs.

**About** link works from **Home** because it is a relative path, and home path has no sublevels.

**Life** page has a `/category` sublevel so the **About** relative page will try to access to `/category/about` which gives 404.

Solution is to set the **about** page and other categories as full paths, not relative:

```
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{'category/life/index.html' | absolute_url }}">Life</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{'aboutme.html'|absolute_url}}">About</a>
        </li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I used to see others' codes like that but I never understood why...Thanks again.